# Parallelizing MPI code in function called from main

Tags: c, linux, function, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a serial code in C, that I want to parallelize using MPI,
but I want to parallelize a region of the code that is not in main,
it is in another function.

For example:

```
main(){
  int a
  int b
  int c

  while (a>0){
    function_a()
  }
}

function_a(){
  int d,e,f,g     
  function_b(d, e)
  function_b(f, g)

}
```

Then, what i want to do is something like

```
 function_a(){
  int d,e,f,g
  if (myrank == 0){
     function_b(d, e)
  }else if (myrank == 1) {
     function_b(f, g)
  }
 }
```

I have done some codes, like summing elements in a big array, but really i am a beginner in MPI.
Please any suggestions are welcome

Comment: I would recommend looking into OpenMP. This is supported by many compilers (gcc and MS included). It is well designed for using multiple threads to handle processing data without you having to worry about all the thread management yourself.

Comment: What is your difficulties here? You can launch your program with only two process (with `mpirun -n 2`), call `MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);` to know what is the instance rank and choose the `function_b` parameters given the `rank` as your snippet shows.